# Apt update command took 213503982334601 days to complete (that's what it says)

Tags: apt, 18.04, time, clock

I ran `sudo apt update` command and to my surprise, it took 213503982334601 days to fetch 7945 kB from Internet. (all other output was normal)
The actual wall clock time, of course, wasn't that big, not even comparable.
But I'd like to find what causes this, if possible. Anyone knows if this is a known issue?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well, now we know what was going on before our universe began.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little bit more searching, seems like it's some 2 year old issue https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5qpmbu/it_took_longer_than_the_age_of_the_universe_for/

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1783190

> fix released

but apparently not for 18.04

Comment: That bug was reported only on cosmic (18.10).  Please consider reporting it for 18.04 (bionic) and it may get fixed (backported) on 18.04 (it can't be until it's reported on launchpad)